# Google Authentication JS API is redirecting to the wrong URL

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I've been using this code below for a couple years and it was working fine until a month ago.

**MY_CUSTOM_URL** is declared and registered on Google Authorized redirect URIs.

```
        function initClient() {   
                    gapi.client.init({
                        apiKey: APKEY,
                        clientId: CLIENTID,
                        discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"],
                        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
                        redirect_uri: MY_CUSTOM_URL,
                        ux_mode: 'redirect',                
                    }).then(function () {                    
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);                        
updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

                    });
                }
```

When I try to call the `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();`, it just ignores **MY_CUSTOM_URL** and redirects to the default website root domain, even when I'm using localhost (which is also registered on Google), and the authentication is not made.

If I comment the **ux_mode**, it opens a **popup** and works properly, but I can't use a popup for this purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

from [Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

> Required. Determines where the API server redirects the user after the
>   user completes the authorization flow. **The value must exactly match
>   one of the redirect_uri values listed for your project in the API
>   Console**. Note that the http or https scheme, case, and trailing slash
>   ('/') must all match.

check redirect_uri in [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) ,make it match your ***MY_CUSTOM_URL***

here is where you can find it

select api => credintals =>choose OAuth 2.0 client IDs => Authorized redirect URIs *[input field]*

Comment: Thank you @essam eg, but I've already triple checked the URLs.

Comment: please check console log, tell us if there is any error or warning

Comment: No errors, it just redirects to the default website root domain (even when I'm localhost it redirects me to the production domain)

Comment: thanks for your support, I've just found the problem and it's really embarassing... I had a custom javascript redirect on the top of the page that happend to match the google callback url.